# Delete lines that match an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, scripting

I have a file full of lines, and I would like to delete any lines that match strings in an array, with PowerShell:

```
$stringsiDoNotWant = @("admin", "student")

$content = gc file.txt
```

but

```
$content = $content -notcontains $StringsiDoNotWant
```

does not work: I still have "admin" and "student" in the variable `$content`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
(Get-Content file.txt) | Where {$_ -notmatch 'admin|student'} | Out-File somefile.txt
```

Or

```
$content = Get-Content file.txt
$content = $content | Where {$_ -notmatch 'admin|student'}
```

Comment: Jeremy: If your array of strings changes, or has a lot of items in it or some such, you can build the string that you match against from an array of strings like this: `$RegExFilter = ($stringsiDoNotWant|%{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"` and then just do your `$_ -notmatch "($RegExFilter)"`

Comment: $content = $content | Where {$_ -notmatch 'admin|student'}
works great, thanks !
I understand that we can't give an array to -notmatch ?

Comment: No, not on the right hand side.  That has to be a regular expression. You can provide an array on the left hand side e.g.`'ab','bc','cd' -notmatch 'a'`.